# Why is my code for finding LCM and HCF is failing in different test cases?

Tags: c++

I wrote a program to find the HCF and LCM of a number. It works fine for some test cases but not for all.
Here is my code:

```
vector<long long> lcmAndGcd(long long A , long long B) {
        long long a=A, b=B;
        long long hcf=1, lcm;
        while(a>0&&b>0)
        {
            if(a>b)
                a=a%b;
            else
                b=b%a;
        }
        hcf=(a==0)?b:a;
        long long start=max(A,B);
        long long i=1;
        while(1)
        {
            start=start*i;
            if(start%A==0&&start%B==0)
                {
                    lcm=start;
                    break;
                }
            i++;
        }
        return {lcm,hcf};
    }
```

I entered `113094 9449384` as input.
The expected output is `534334317048 2`.
But I am getting
`0 2`.

After doing the changes with 'start' variables:

```
vector<long long> lcmAndGcd(long long A , long long B) {
    long long a=A, b=B;
    long long hcf=1, lcm;
    while(a>0&&b>0)
    {
        if(a>b)
            a=a%b;
        else
            b=b%a;
    }
    hcf=(a==0)?b:a;
    long long start=max(A,B);
    long long org = start;
    while(1)
    {
        if(start%A==0&&start%B==0)
            {
                lcm=start;
                break;
            }
            start=start+org;
    }
    return {lcm,hcf};
}
```

Comment: Simpler method `lcm = (A/hcf)*B;`

Comment: I know that approach, I just wanted to try implementing my own logic.

Comment: *I just wanted to try implementing my own logic.* -- What debugging have you done?  If it's your own logic, a requirement is for you to debug your own code to see where it fails.

Comment: @NickRaise Use a debugger, but what I think is happening is that you loop proceeds until `i` wraps around until eventually `i` is zero. At that point `start` also equals zero and so your if statement in the loop is true and you return zero.

Comment: @NickRaise I wonder if you are forgetting that when you execute `start=start*i` you have already changed the value of `start` on  a previous iteration of the loop. You aren't multiplying the original value.

Comment: Yes, the problem with my code was that when the loop iterate, I wanted the multiples of 'start' variable but instead, the original value of 'start' get changed with every iterations.

Comment: why are there two versions of your code in the question? What changes have you made to the `start` variable and why? And did the results improve?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number , I wanted the 'start' variable to contain the multiple of its value with every iteration, but the logical statement that I wrote for it in the loop was wrong.
example:  consider 'start' = 5, I wanted: 5*1 5*2 5*3 5*4........,
   Instead I was getting: 5*1 5*2 10*3 30*4....
The second snippet of code is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You multiply `start` in every cycle in the loop in the first code snippet.

The **correct** code would be:

```
while (true)
{
    long long end = start * i;
    if (end % A == 0 && end % B == 0)
    {
        lcm = end;
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Even if this multiplication would be a part of your logic, you very soon get overflow even for *long long*.

The second code snippet works fine.